# how to use hard disk for installation of Anaconda package

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda package on ubuntu 14.04 Lts,but don't have enough space in the users folder,so wanted to use the hard disk as the destination of the installation.

But when I run the script( **bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh**),it shows permission denied error,can anyone please suggest some way to use the hard disk as the installation directory.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by hard disk?

Comment: the partitions that are present in the hard drive,the ones which have "/media" as the starting in their paths.

Comment: Did you run it with `sudo` prefix?

Comment: yes,still its permission denied

Comment: Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 370: /media/user/K/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1/bin/python: Permission denied

Comment: the error is in the above comment

Comment: The script is trying to execute its own binary `media/user/K/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1/bin/python`, but the media on which it resides doesn't support Linux executable permissions (either because of its file system - a FAT or NTFS USB for example) or because it's mounted with the `noexec` or `showexec` option.

Comment: ohk,thanks,is there any way to install it in that partition?

Comment: which file system is compatible with Linux?